# Why startup switch won't run macro

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I'm trying to create a Windows that runs a macro after Word starts. I can't figure out why the following doesn't work.

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\WINWORD.EXE" /mDiaryDateDayofWeek

I've played around with the format slightly and all I can get it to do is either start up and beep or start up and do nothing.

This is what Microsoft.com says about the startup switch.

/mmacroname

Starts Word and then runs a specific macro. The /m switch also prevents Word from running any AutoExec macros.

Example    To start Word and then run the macro Salelead, type the following at the command prompt:

/mSalelead

Comment: Where is this macro? If not in normal.dotx you'll need to load the file with it.

Comment: Thank you. I assume it's in Normal since it's a macro that I can use in any new document I create. Normal is also listed at the top of that tree in the Edit Macro editor. I've also spell checked the macro. Does your reply mean my syntax is correct? I played around with the format and found there is a space between the path and the switch code.

Answer (score 0):

You want the macro to be in the Normal.dotm file.

If you want a macro to run when you start Word, the easiest method is to save it in your Normal.dotm file with the name AutoExec. You only need the command-line method if you may be running different macros.

Comment: The thing is I don't want it to run every time I start word. Most of the time I don't need it to run.

Comment: Your switch /mSalelead should run the macro (and stop any AutoExec macro from running. You can create a Windows shortcut to start Word using this command line switch if you want. There must be a space between Winword.exe and the /.